# Why did South African soldiers choose EO over UNITA?

Tags: armed-conflict, africa, south-africa, angola, private-military-companies

This is a question concerning  [Executive Outcomes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executive_Outcomes) and [UNITA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNITA). I concede this question is slightly Tom Clancy-esque, but I think now that these events have been largely declassified all these decades later, the time for speculating is over and now it's time to have a serious political analysis. Here is a quote from [Simon Mann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_Mann):

> The weird thing was that most of the South Africans with us [EO], had
>   it been literally years or even months before, would have been
>   fighting on the other side [UNITA]. Because they would have been South
>   African soldiers backed by America.

### Question

What political circumstances/conditions made it appealing for South African soldiers to choose EO? I understand Mann's logic up until a point, but I feel that I need to see the larger political landscape to put it into context.

On a side note, if you disagree with Mann's premise, feel free to answer through whatever lens you see fit.

Comment: Surely it has to do with the fall of apartheid? I guess you're talking about Mann's actions in Angola. If those were in 1993, wouldn't that have been during the beginning of the process of dismantling apartheid?

Comment: Simon Mann comments on it in [this video](https://youtu.be/o9iIp7CxgaA?t=480).

Comment: Well, were they even South African soldiers? I thought they were *former* soldiers. And weren't there South African mercenaries on both sides?

Comment: What do you mean by "choose"? As in join an indigenous insurgent force?

Comment: I understand the sentence as "As SA soldiers, the SA government did **order** them to fight as allies of UNITA; once they were no longer SA soldiers but mercenaries they (or *some* of them) did **chose** to fight in EO (perhaps for the money?)" Not an answer as I lack knowledge of the issues of the region, but that is as I read the sentence.